How to represent an int64 value in JSON for GRPC?
I have a problem with GRPC representing int64 values in JSON.
I have a protobuf definition I'm using:
syntax = "proto3";
package foo;

message Bar {
    string spec = 1;
    int64 compatibility_key = 3;
}

and I'm using a JSON representation like this:
{
  "Bar": {
    "spec": "somepath/somefile.txt",
    "compatibility_key": "17457183487633360448"
  }
}

But when I try to parse this JSON using google::protobuf::util::JsonStringToMessage(json_string, msg);
I get
Expected equality of these values:
  google::protobuf::util::OkStatus()
    Which is: OK
  pb_status
    Which is: INVALID_ARGUMENT:(Bar.compatibility_key): invalid value "17457183487633360448" for type TYPE_INT64

So - what is the correct way to represent this value in JSON?   The docs all say that my representation should be correct

17457183487633360448 is too large to be held in an int64

9,223,372,036,854,775,807 is the max int64 value and you're trying to store :
17,457,183,487,633,360,448 <-- this is too big.   If the service you're interfacing with needs an int64 choose something in range.

@DazWilkin had it right - I needed to have uint64 instead of int64; now everybody's happy.
